# Hanging indents for List of Tables using tocloft

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I am trying to format a List of Tables using tocloft, and I am having a devil of a time figuring out how to have hanging indents, where for long captions every line after the first is indented by a specific amount. Is this even possible in tocloft?

Here is a MWE:

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}


\begin{document}

\listoftables
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
\hline
cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{This is an extremely long table caption, which will need to be    hanging indented inside of the list of tables, }
\end{center}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: By how much should the second line (and any following lines) be indented?

Comment: By an arbitrary amount, say 10pt?

Comment: Hmmm, I thought this was going to be straightforward to achieve, e.g., by issuing the command `\renewcommand\cfttabaftersnumb{\hangindent=10pt\hangafter=1}`. However, that doesn't seem to work. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What works in the toc doesn't work in the caption, so you will need to specify both (especially if you don't want hanging indentation in the caption).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand{\mycaption}[1]% duplicate long and short captions
{\caption[\addtolength{\leftskip}{\bibindent}\hspace{-\bibindent}#1]{#1}}

\captionsetup{format=hang}

\begin{document}

\listoftables
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
\hline
cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\mycaption{This is an extremely long table caption, which will need to be    hanging indented inside of the list of tables, }
\end{center}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```